# How to click a radio button that is in a worksheet (not in a userform but on a worksheet)

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I have a worksheet (that I can't change) that contains radio button.  It should be easy, but I can't fin a way to click on a specific radio button.  Those buttons have code associated with it (Private Sub OptionButtonQ1Oui_Click), but what I need to do is to "click" on it using vba.

I tried pretty much all the options I could think of and none are working.  Here are different options I tried with no luck

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Grille")
ws.Range("OptionButtonQ2Non").Value = 1
ws.OptionButtonQ2Non.Value = True
OptionButtonQ2Non_Click
Worksheets("Input").Shapes ("OptionButtonQ2Non").value

ws.Shapes("OptionButtonQ2Non").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
ws.Shapes("OptionButtonQ2Non").select
ws.Shapes("OptionButtonQ2Non").Value = True
```

I'm sure it's pretty easy, but I just can't find the answer anywhere.  All the info I can find refers to option button used in a userform, which is not my case, since the option buttons I want to control are simply placed in a worksheet.

Any idea someone?
Thanks in advance

I'm updating my question based on help from @bigben.
So see code below, one way is working the other is giving me error message.
why this is not the same?

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("test")

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim nom As String
sheetname= "test"

wb.Sheets(sheetname).OptionButton1_Click          'this works
wb.ws.OptionButton1_Click                   'this gives "run time error 438:  Object doesn't support this property or method"

wb.Sheets(sheetname).OptionButton1.Value = True          'this gives "run time error 438:  Object doesn't support this property or method"
wb.ws.OptionButton1.Value = True                    'this gives "run time error 438:  Object doesn't support this property or method"


End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear but tried it already with        OptionButtonQ2Non_Click      any idea why it's not working?

Comment: yes error message

Comment: I had to reproduce it at home…  "Compile error, sub or function not defined"

Comment: In a different module (module 1 is where "Option..  _click "  is called )  and the code related to the button is placed in the worksheets "code".  e.g.  (Private Sub OptionButton1_Click)  but my goal is to have the button to be clicked...

Comment: Then I get "Compile Error:   Method or data member not found"  on "OptionButtonQ1Oui_Click"

Comment: We're getting there...  I had already did it, but I had my worksheet declared;  " Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("test").  That was giving me the "compile error".  If I replace ws.optionbutton…    by sheet1optionbutton...  then it runs smoothly.  And off course, sheet1  is equal to "Worksheets("test").  Any other thoughts you could share?

Comment: I've update my question, to be more specific.  Tx again BigBen for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a Form control then this will help

```
Dim opt As OptionButton
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Grille")
Set opt = ws.Shapes("Option Button 1").OLEFormat.Object
opt.Value = True
```

If it is an ActiveX control then this will help

```
Dim opt As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Grille")
Set opt = ws.OLEObjects("OptionButton1")
opt.Object.Value = True
```

Comment: Thank you so much Siddarth.  It's always a very "humbling" experience to compare my knowledge to the one of a real master like you.